# The omission of 'should' in the present subjunctive clauses or other clauses

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, present-subjunctive

For example, 1. Lee urged that Mara Bianchi (**should**) be promoted to export manager. (command)
2. Alice recommended that a sales representative (**should**) be sent to South Africa. (advice)
3. Alice reported that the Delaware Bridge project **should** be completed by August next year. (report something, can't omit 'should')
4. Simon insisted that work schedules (**should**) be kept to. (suggest)
5. Simon instructed that all monthly reports (**should**) be sent to him directly. (command)
6. Alina suggested that web conferencing (**should**) be used for meetings to save money on airfares. (suggest)
7. Alina declared that the company's head office (**should**) remain in London. (suggest)
8. Nathan agreed that the company **should** sponsor the European Chess League for the next three years. (agree, can't omit 'should')
9. Nathan announced that in the future, all claims for travel expenses **should** be made in US dollars. (announce, can't omit 'should')
I am quite confused about whether the word 'should' can be omitted in sentences. As I searched it online, I learned about the usage of should, which can be omitted when it's used with some verbs such as advise, suggest, and command.   Am I right in the above examples?   Can we omit 'should' whether in the conditional sentence or subjunctive clause?    Is 'should' still a modal verb in a subjunctive clause?

Comment: Clauses with "should" are not subjunctive, though they are mandative.